# Null Pointer Exception when splitting to String Array

Tags: java, jsp, multidimensional-array, nullpointerexception, filereader

So I'm trying to populate two arrays from a file reader. Which I believe requires nested loops. I think I'm on the right track but I've been a little stuck since yesterday. The purpose of this program is to initiate the program through a jsp and to read in the values dynamically. Any help would really be appreciated. I think I'm on the right track but I can't seem to finish it on my own. The first line of fxRates.csv should be populated into the currencyCodes Array and the rest of the lines should be populated into the 2d array fxExchangeRates. I got the code to not have any errors but now all I get is this when I try to run the program: [image]

Here is the error log:

```
 Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Warning:   Ignore WEB-INF/sun-web.xml in archive /G:/School/Java II/Labs/MidtermAD/build/web/, as WLS counterpart runtime xml WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml is present in the same archive.
Info:   Loading application [MidtermAD] at [/MidtermAD]
Info:   MidtermAD was successfully deployed in 464 milliseconds.
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2337)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2422)
    at data.FxDataModel.<init>(FxDataModel.java:38)
    at org.apache.jsp.fxCalc_jsp.jspInit(fxCalc_jsp.java:45)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:92)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:210)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

fxInit.jsp:

```
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ page import="data.FxDataModel"%>
<%!

private FxDataModel fxDataModel;


        public void jspInit(){
        Properties fxProps = new Properties();


        ServletContext context = getServletContext();
        fxProps.getProperty(FxDataModel.FX_PRP_FILE_NAME_KEY);

        context.getRealPath(context.getInitParameter(FxDataModel.FX_PRP_FILE_NAME_KEY));

        try{
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(FxDataModel.FX_PRP_FILE_NAME_KEY);
            fxProps.load(input);
            input.close();
        }catch(IOException e){

           FileInputStream input = null;
        }
        context.getRealPath(fxProps.getProperty(FxDataModel.FX_RATE_FILE_NAME_KEY));
        try{
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(FxDataModel.FX_RATE_FILE_NAME_KEY);
            fxProps.load(input);
            input.close();
        }catch(IOException e){

            FileInputStream input = null;
        }

        fxDataModel = new FxDataModel(fxProps);


        }
%>
```

FxDataModel.Java:

```
package data;

import java.util.*;


public class FxDataModel {

   public static final String FX_PRP_FILE_NAME_KEY = "fx.prp.file.name";
   public static final String FX_RATE_FILE_NAME_KEY = "fx.rates.file.name";
   public static final String FX_RATES_FILE_DLMTR_KEY = "fx.rates.file.dlmtr";
   public static final String SRC_AMT_KEY = "src.amt";
   public static final String SRC_CUCY_KEY = "src.cucy";
   public static final String DST_AMT_KEY = "dst.amt";
   public static final String DST_CUCY_KEY = "dst.cucy";

   private Properties fxProps = new Properties();

   private double [][] fxExchangeRates;
   private String[] fxCurrencies;

   public FxDataModel(Properties fxProps)      
         {
          this.fxProps = fxProps;  
          String[] rateStrings;
          String record;
          fxProps .setProperty(FX_RATES_FILE_DLMTR_KEY,"fx.rates.file.dlmtr");
          String delimiter = fxProps.getProperty(FX_RATES_FILE_DLMTR_KEY);
          Scanner reader = new Scanner(FX_RATE_FILE_NAME_KEY);


                  fxCurrencies = reader.nextLine().split(delimiter);

       for( int i = 0 ; i < fxCurrencies.length ; i++ ){

           record= reader.nextLine();
           rateStrings = record.split(delimiter);
           fxExchangeRates[i] = new double[fxCurrencies.length];

          for( int j = 0 ; j < rateStrings.length ; j++ ){

          fxExchangeRates[i][j]= Double.parseDouble(rateStrings[j]);

        }

        reader.close();

       }

         }

         public Properties getFxProps()

         {


           return fxProps;


         }
   public String[] getFxCurrencies(){
       return fxCurrencies;
   }

   public double getFxRate(final String inNumber, final String outNumber){

       int Currency1;
       int Currency2;
       double rate;

        for(Currency1 = 0; Currency1 <getFxCurrencies().length; Currency1++){ 

            if(inNumber.equals(fxCurrencies[Currency1])){
                break;
            }
        }

         for(Currency2 = 0; Currency2 <getFxCurrencies().length; Currency2++){ 

            if(outNumber.equals(fxCurrencies[Currency2])){
                break;
            }
        }


         rate = fxExchangeRates[Currency1][Currency2];
         return rate;

        }

   }
```

fxCalc.jsp

```
    <%@include file="fxInit.jsp"%>
<%      
        Properties fxProps = fxDataModel.getFxProps();
        String srcAmtName = fxProps.getProperty(FxDataModel.SRC_AMT_KEY );
        String dstAmtName = fxProps.getProperty(FxDataModel.DST_AMT_KEY );
        String srcCucyName = fxProps.getProperty(FxDataModel.SRC_CUCY_KEY );
        String dstCucyName = fxProps.getProperty(FxDataModel.DST_CUCY_KEY );
        String Curr1 = request.getParameter(srcAmtName);
        String Curr2 = request.getParameter(dstAmtName);
        String formInput;
        String formOutput;

        String[] currencies = fxDataModel.getFxCurrencies();


        try {

          formInput = request.getParameter(srcAmtName);
          Double formDouble = Double.parseDouble(formInput);
          Double Conversion = fxDataModel.getFxRate(Curr1,Curr2)*formDouble;
          formOutput = String.valueOf(Conversion);

         } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
             Curr1= Curr2 = currencies[0];
             formInput = ("");
             formOutput = ("");   
         } catch (NullPointerException npe){

            Curr1= Curr2 = currencies[0];
            formInput = ("");
            formOutput = ("");

        }

%>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>F/X Calculator</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <style>

        h1{
            color: white;
            font-family: verdana;
            font-size: 200%;
            font-style: italic;
            text-align: center;
        }
        hr{
            color:white;

        }

        select{
            margin-top: 30px;
            margin-right:10px;
        }
        input{

            margin-top: 30px;
            margin-right:10px;
        }
    </style>


    <body bgcolor = "blue">

        <h1>
            Money Banks F/X Calculator<br>
        </h1>
        <hr>
        <div align="center">
        <form name ="fxCalc" action="fxCalc.jsp" method="POST">


        <select name="<%=srcCucyName%>">
            <% for (String currency : currencies) { %>
              <option value="<%=currency%>" <%=currency.equals(Curr1)?"selected":""%>><%=currency%></option>
            <%}%>
        </select>


            <input name="<%=srcAmtName%>" type="text" value = <%=formInput%> >

        <select name="<%=dstCucyName%>">
            <% for (String currency : currencies) { %>
              <option value="<%=currency%>" <%=currency.equals(Curr2)?"selected":""%>><%=currency%></option>
            <%}%>
        </select>


            <input name="<%=dstAmtName%>" type="text" disabled="disabled" value = <%=formOutput%>>

            <br>


            <input name="submitbutton" type="submit" value="Convert" name="Convert"/>
            <input name="resetbutton" type="reset" value="Reset"/>  




       <form/> 
       <div/>
    </body>
</html>
```

One thing I'm really not understanding is that I'm not supposed to "hard code" the form controls in the html so that is why these "SRC_AMT_KEY" keys were provided. I'm just not sure exactly how to implement them. I tried my best but I don't understand this part entirely. Are the keys supposed to replace variables like "Curr1" and "Curr2"? This is how the application worked before but we are updating it now so that nothing is hard coded. I would really appreciate any help in understanding this project. I've been stuck on it for a couple days now and I will continue to update the code if I make any progress. Thank you!

Here are also the contents of the fxCalc.prp file:

```
dst.amt=dstAmt
dst.cucy=dstCucy
fx.rates.file.dlmtr=,
fx.rates.file.name=/WEB-INF/fxRates.csv
src.amt=srcAmt
src.cucy=srcCucy
```

The fxRates.csv file also contains these codes:

```
CAD,EUR,GBP,USD
1.0,0.624514066,0.588714763,0.810307
1.601244959,1.0,0.942676548,1.2975
1.698615463,1.060809248,1.0,1.3764
1.234100162,0.772200772,.726532984,1.0
```

Comment: Too much code. Provide only what is relevant. [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Okay.. Thanks. I deleted a few things and narrowed down the problem.

Comment: You never populated the `fxProps` properties with any values.

Comment: TL;DR; Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Off-Topic: You should let your [adoring](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/3oywzi/teacher_bashes_student_in_answer_on_stackoverflow/)... [public](https://what.thedailywtf.com/t/no-stackoverflow-for-you/51861)... know how things go.

Comment: @WernerCD yeah I posted a little response on reddit about the situation.

Comment: What school do you go to?
I want to avoid putting my kid in that school. :P

Answer (score 2):

In FxDataModel.Java class 
you declared the properties reference as `private Properties fxProps;`

but you didn't assign Properties Object. By default it assigned with `null`, on null value you are calling `fxProps.getProperty( FX_RATES_FILE_DLMTR_KEY );`. So then at run-time the JVM throws NullPointerException.

**Solution:**

```
private Properties fxProps = new Properties();
fxProps .setProperty(FX_RATES_FILE_DLMTR_KEY,"fx.rates.file.dlmtr");
private String delimiter = fxProps.getProperty( FX_RATES_FILE_DLMTR_KEY );
```

Comment: Check the update on FxDataModel.Java
I did what you suggested but I still get a NullPointerException.
It always points back to line 38 which is when I split the first line of the file using the delimiter.

Comment: If JVM trows an error like

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2337)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2422)

If and only if the delimiter value is null. 

Here in your case :


          String delimiter = fxProps.getProperty( FX_RATES_FILE_DLMTR_KEY );  // Returning null
          
                  fxCurrencies = reader.nextLine().split(delimiter);

So, that split(null) method throws NullPointerException.

Comment: How can delimiter be null though. I set it as  String delimiter = fxProps.getProperty( FX_RATES_FILE_DLMTR_KEY ); and I initiated fxProps like you told me. Could there be something else thats causing the value to be null?

Comment: Yes,,

your providing delimiter value as null. (fxProps.getProperty( FX_RATES_FILE_DLMTR_KEY ) returns null) That is why it throws Exception.

Comment: What can I do to fix it? How come (fxProps.getProperty( FX_RATES_FILE_DLMTR_KEY ) isn't returning the value from the file? Its even define as:  public static final String FX_RATES_FILE_DLMTR_KEY = "fx.rates.file.dlmtr"; That's why I'm so confused.

Comment: Because "fx.rates.file.dlmtr" is not available in the Properties class right.  If you want to get the properties, you must set the property before. where did you set the "fx.rates.file.dlmtr" property in Properties class.

Comment: you should set the property before getting.

Comment: Well the properties class is part of java right? Im just using the properties object to pass the properties of a file. I'm still new to this. Thats why I included as much of my code as possible.

Comment: you can find the updated answer how to set the properties to Properties class. Or else you can go with the below

http://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/java/properties-class-example-in-java.html

Comment: When I  did i what is in the updated solution
fxProps.setProperty(FX_RATES_FILE_DLMTR_KEY,"fx.rates.file.dlmtr"); just get highlighted and it says it cannot find that symbol/

Comment: Okay so I now I get this: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Any idea why? I mean the fxRates.csv file is there. I'm just not sure while the scanner can't access it? I've updated my code with what I have now.  When I make the scanner: Scanner reader = new Scanner(fxProps.getProperty(FX_RATE_FILE_NAME_KEY)); and I run it, I still get a null pointer exception.